# Solaris 10: how to run correct tcp wrappers?

Tags: solaris, tcp-wrappers

I want to deny ftp access on solaris10
For experiment i use only one host
Tcp wrapper is enabled

```
inetadm -l ftp | grep tcp_wrappers
default  tcp_wrappers=TRUE
```

/etc/hosts.deny

```
ftpd: 192.168.0.2
in.ftpd: 192.168.0.2
```

But when i try to log in with ftp with 192.168.0.2 it work
why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found,was overwritten by /etc/hosts.allow wich contain

```
in.ftpd: ALL
```

i change to

```
in.ftpd: ALL EXCEPT 192.168.0.2
```